# jquery first Friday of the month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to get first Friday of each month from jQuery Datepicker? I'm just enabling Friday's on Datepicker which is working perfectly however problem comes in when new month starts and date does not reach to Friday yet. Datepicker should not display the current month until first Friday arrived because all dates will be disabled.

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '03/01/2013',
        maxDate: 0M,
        beforeShowDay:
            function (dt) {
                return [dt.getDay() == 5, ""];
            }
    });
```

Comment: you should show the code you are currently using for enabling Fridays

Comment: Can you post some code or maybe even set up a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Here it is.

```
    //var currentDate = new Date('07/04/2013');
    //var currentDate = new Date('06/06/2013');
    //var currentDate = new Date('05/06/2013');
    //var currentDate = new Date('05/03/2013');
    //var currentDate = new Date('05/02/2013');

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var lastFriday;

    if (currentDate.getDay() == 5 || currentDate.getDate() >= 7) {
        lastFriday = currentDate.format("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
    else if (currentDate.getDate() < 7) {

        var days = new Array();
        var isFridayPast = false;
        var x = 0;
        var gd = currentDate.getDate();

        for (var i = 7; i > 0; i--) {
            days[x] = gd--;                
            var dayName = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), days[x]).toDateString().substring(0, 3);                
            if (dayName == "Fri") {
                isFridayPast = true
                lastFriday = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), days[x]).format("MM/dd/yyyy");                    
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isFridayPast == false) {
            lastFriday = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), -(7 - currentDate.getDay())).format("MM/dd/yyyy");                
        }
    }

 $("#dp").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: '03/01/2013',
    maxDate: lastFriday,
    beforeShowDay:
        function (dt) {
            return [dt.getDay() == 5, ""];
        }
});
```